# Unity ImagePicker iOS

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пожалуйста обьясните как делается запрос из С# в objective-C и обратно,
нужно сделать изменение аватарки в игре с возможностью выбора из галерей но как получить картинку или адрес... Вообще как взаимодействовать между этими 2 языками, заранее благодарен, вопрос от новичка в програмировании

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы реализовать нужный вам функционал, потребуется написать нативный плагин на Objective-c и работать с ним через C# код. По данной теме, у меня написана [статья на habrahabr](https://habrahabr.ru/post/266893/), где создание плагина разбирается на основе плагина facebook. Также на эту тему есть [официальная документация](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html), хотя она немного сумбурно.

По поводу выбора изображения из галереи можно почитать [здесь](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/ios-image-picker-controller).

Comment: Примного благодарен за уделение внимания этой трашной для меня проблемы )